# c++ function that finds average, sum, min and max of n numbers passed in

Tags: c++

Good afternoon,I was asked to make a function called void printStatistics(int n) which should print the average, sum, min and max number of n numbers passed in to it. for example if I did printStatistics(5) then I should ask the user to enter a number 5 times then print the stats.
All I managed to do was create a while loop that asked the user for a number until a negative number was entered, but I seem to have some trouble turning it into a function that asks the user to enter a number n times and then printing out the sum, average, min and max.This is what I have.

```
int main()
{
    int value, sum;
    int average, min, max;
    int count;

    sum = 0;
    count = 0;

    cout << "Enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> value;

    min = value;
    max = value;

    while(value >= 0)
    {
        sum += value;
        count++;
        if(value > max)
            max = value;
        else if(value < min)
            min = value;

        cout << "Enter a numnber: " << endl;
        cin >> value;
    }
    if(count == 0)
        cout << "Nothing entered." << endl;
    else
    {
        average = sum / count;
        cout << "Average is " << average << endl;
        cout << "Minimum is " << min << endl;
        cout << "Maximum is " << max << endl;
        cout << "Sum is " << sum << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are seeking help finding a bug, I recommend adding the include statements to complete the code and present a runnable sample, an example of your inputs, the resulting output, and your expected output. Right now you are falling short of the requirement for a [mcve].

Comment: A note: You seem to be using `value` for all of your input. This is overwriting the counter you need to have in order to know when to stop collecting input.

Comment: You forget to compute `average`, you forget first value in `sum`...

Comment: The initialization of `min` and `max` from `value` is an error. `min` should be the highest possible value the user can input so that whatever value the user proves it will be lower than or equal to., Similarly `max` should be the lowest so that input will be higher or equal. Currently if all values given are over the initial value of `min`, min will not change and the wrong value will be reported.

Comment: Also note that `average` is declared as integer, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood from your question, you wish to have a function (printStatistics) that takes the parameter of 'int n' with 'n' corresponding to the amount of numbers the user wishes to enter. Then you ask for those specific numbers, then find the MIN, MAX, SUM, and AVERAGE of that set. If I understood this correctly, then this should do the trick:

```
#include <iostream>

void printStatistics(int n);


void printStatistics(int n)
{
    int response;
    int sum = 0;
    int max;
    int min;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the number in the " << i << " position: ";
        std::cin >> response;
        if (i == 1)
        {
            min = response;
            max = response;
        }
        (min > response) ? min = response : min = min;
        (max < response) ? max = response : max = max;
        sum += response;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum: " << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Average: " << (float)sum / n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Min: " << min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Max: " << max << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    int numberCount;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "How many numbers would you like to print? ";
        std::cin >> numberCount;
    }while(numberCount <= 0);
    printStatistics(numberCount);   
}
```

Comment: @user4581301 Oh yes that would be much better! Nice one, allow me to edit my code.

Comment: Worth taking @Samantha 's comment to the question into account as well.